# Fetch address and birthday from android contacts in one query

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I want to fetch id,name,birthday,addess from android contacts. I changed the uri (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds, ContactsContract.Contacts etc.) and was able to fetch the address, but then the birthday disappeared. Anyway I tried, I can not find a solution to fetch both at once.

```
public void getBirthdays() {

    // get data from contacts
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS};

    String selection =
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        Common.echo(cursor.getColumnName(i) + ", " + cursor.getString(i));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

the output of the above code is:

```
I: contact_id, 14046
I: display_name, Magret XXXX
I: data1, XXXX-05-31
I: data1, XXXX-05-31
```

The "data1"-field is listed twice, because START_DATE (birthday) and FORMATTED_ADDRESS are both stored in same virtual column "data1".

Is there a way to define a virtual column-names in a resolver like the SQL-equivalent "SELECT col1 AS name1, col2 AS name2, col3,col4 WHERE..."?

Answer (score 0):

two issues: you're limiting your query to `EVENT`s only & you're only logging the first row found in the query.

Try this:

```
private class Contact {
    public Long contactId;
    public String name;
    public String birthday;
    public String address;
}

public void getBirthdaysAndAddress() {

    // mapping from contactId to a contact object 
    Map<Long, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<>();

    Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            Data.CONTACT_ID,
            Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Data.MIMETYPE,
            Data.DATA1,
            Event.TYPE};

    // get ALL rows that represent either a birthday or a postal address
    String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Long id = cursor.getLong(0);

        // get an existing contact object, or create a new one
        Contact contact = contacts.get(id);
        if (contact == null) {
            contact = new Contact();
            contact.contactId = id;
            contact.name = cursor.getString(1);
            contacts.put(id, contact);
        }

        String mimetype = cursor.getString(2);
        if (mimetype.equals(Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            // this is an event row, check that it is a birthday
            int type = cursor.getInt(4);
            if (type == Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY) {
                contact.birthday = cursor.getString(3);
            }
        } else {
            // this is an address row
            contact.address = cursor.getString(3);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    // print all contact objects containing a birthday
    Iterator it = mp.values().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Contact contact = (Contact) it.next();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contact.birthday)) {
            Log.i("Birthday contacts", contact.contactId + " - " + contact.name + " - " + contact.birthday + " - " + contact.address);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that's not the solution. @1: I ONLY want contacts with a birthday (limitation is OK) @2: I only logged one row for a small log (in my app I go through all). But in your code, you get twice the address instead of twice the birthday (like in my code). The problem is, that both [address AND birthday] are resolved in the virtual column "data1". I hoped for sth. like SELECT Event.START_DATE AS birthday, StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS AD address WHERE... but that does not work, because it is a resolver instead of a database (better said: to access the database).

Comment: i think you have a bit of a confusion there, each row in data represent a single data type, you can use the MIMETYPE column to figure out what the current row represents. The fact that both of your requested types are using Data.data1 is not an issue. I'll add some code to my answer to show what I mean

Comment: you are right, I know about the data-representation. I'm looking for a way to "redirect" the address-output to another column as the MIME-typed output of the birthday, that both can be fetched at once. I "solved" my problem by fetching first [id,name,birthday] to fill my database and after that I fetch [id,address] and do an UPDATE over the same database, but that is a bad and inefficent "solution". It would be good, if the content-resolver would support alias-columns.